GPU Usage by QueryNode
In the case of GPU indexes like GPU_CAGRA, GPU_IVF_FLAT, etc., when I load the collection, does the entire index gets loaded from the storage bucket to the CPU memory first, and then, based on the query, a subset of these indexes is loaded into the GPU memory pool?
If that’s the case, what happens if, for example, I have 10GB of CPU memory and 100GB of GPU memory? Will the maximum amount of index data I can load for search be limited to 10GB due to the lower CPU memory, potentially leading to under utilization of my GPU?

Technically, the load process loads segments by multiple threads into CPU memory, then copies the data into GPU memory. Once a segment's index is copied into GPU memory, its data in CPU memory is freed. So, if the parallel loading tasks are controlled under 10GB, it can be successfully loaded.
To seg the thread pool for load process, set these values to 1. (These values are integer type)
common:
  threadCoreCoefficient:
    highPriority: 1 # This parameter specify how many times the number of threads is the number of cores in high priority pool
    middlePriority: 1 # This parameter specify how many times the number of threads is the number of cores in middle priority pool
    lowPriority: 1 # This parameter specify how many times the number of threads is the number of cores in low priority pool

If the query node has 5 CPU cores, the pool size is 1 * 5 = 5, which means there will be 5 threads to load the segments parallelly. By default, a segment size is around 1GB, so it is safe for 5 CPU cores. But if the number of CPU cores is 10, it might return an error message saying "load segment failed, OOM if load."
